# Finding CodeBlocks that works or fixing bugs?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, bug

I am using Codeblocks to develop C++ code on OSX Mavericks. I am currently running into the problem where the software occasionally will crash and than continue to crash every time the software is started again. I know for this software package there is a bunch of different sources: code blocks pre built apt, mac port version, and I believe even a version you can download through svn or git hub which is the nightly build.

Additionally, I also have problems with the auto complete sometimes not working.

Can someone recommend a version that worked for them with a reasonable explanation on how to install it? Or, if you had similar issues with code blocks, how you went about fixing the bugs?

By the way I am using the pre built 32 bit apt from code blocks website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same issue.

A workaround / fix is to  disable the autocomplete plugin if you consider "works" without autocomplete.